# grouping documents in Vista (temporarily?)

Tags: windows-vista

In Vista, how do I put 4 or 5 documents (poems) into one subission file (temporarily?) for literary publications?  Many publishers do not want poems attached to an email anymore, so you fill out an online form for the publisher, where you upload your poems file.

Microsoft did not understand what I was saying when I asked one of their techs.  If someone knows the answer, I would be more grateful than any words.

Also, I would like to mark a document (poem) when it has been sent out, or mark when it has been published or returned under My Documents.

Comment: Are you asking how to insert a file into MS Word?  Create a new document, open the folder with the file and drag its icon into the document.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to aggregate files into one is to put them in an "archive", like a zip file. This puts a copy of your files into a "shell", usually with compression to make the archive smaller than the sum of the individual files.  There are probably dozens of different archive formats (e.g., zip, rar, tar, etc.).  Some offer special features or better compression than others but for your purpose, you want a format that is "universal" so that the publisher can easily open it.  Zip has been sort of the standard for Windows, and some systems can handle zip files as if they were directory folders without having to even extract the files.  It would be surprizing if a publisher could not open a zip file.

There are a gazillion free programs that will do this (one example is 7-Zip, http://www.7-zip.org/).  If you do a Google search on free zip programs there is no shortage of offerings.

In terms of marking a document, there is no provision to do that as part of Vista.  There might be software that could do that for you or you could just create a "system", like using specific directories to save a copy of the "marked" files.